# Vue.js - Can't use Blazy

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, frontend, lazy-loading

I want to use `Blazy` package to lazy load images in my `Vue.js` project. I installed it via `npm`, but I just can't import it and use it. I put this code in the `created` method of `App.vue`:

`const bLazy = new Blazy({})`

And this code in a component used to display items with images:

`<img src="placeholder" :data-src="image-src" class="w-100 rounded" :alt="name">`

Now what I tried to import it and make it working:

`import Blazy from 'blazy'` => Didn't work.

`import * as Blazy from 'blazy'` => Didn't work.

`require('blazy')` => `"ReferenceError: Blazy is not defined"`.

`const Blazy = require('blazy')` => Didn't work.

**What is the right way to make it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neither a Vue or a npm problem.
Blazy is quite an old library (last updated 2 years ago) and doesn't support the module import syntax (because it isn't a module).
You have two options:

1. Find a better library for this purpose, at best a plugin for Vue.
2. Copy the package's code to a file in your `src` and export the `Blazy` object.